# При выделении конкретного документа справа отобразить содержимое его табличной части

Tags: 1с

Разработать обработку, на форму которой вывести список документов «РасходнаяНакладная». При выделении конкретного документа справа отобразить содержимое его табличной части.

Сама задача описана выше, в документе «РасходнаяНакладная» есть стандартная табличная часть, в ней 4 реквизита (Номенклатура, Количество, Цена, Сумма)

Подскажите как решить или в каком направлении искать ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На форму добавить динамический список, он будет выводить документы "Расходная накладная". Справа добавить таблицу значений. У элемента формы, который будет связан с динамическим списком, обрабатывать событие "ПриАктивизацииСтроки". В данном событии запросом получить данные из документа (по ТЧ) и заполнить в таблицу значений.
Примечание: У элемента списка документов в свойствах отключить множественное выделение. Что бы всегда была позиционность на одну строку.

Comment: оКей, попробую и отпишусь, спасибо

Comment: Спасибо большое. Проблема оказалась не такой сложной, как казалось, причем можно было вообще не обрабатывать событие

Comment: @ck1e, там много вариантов реализации. Что первое в голову пришло, то и озвучил :)